# Is there a way to schedule Exchange 2007 to query and e-mail statistics?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

I work very little with Exchange so I apologize if I seem clueless. What I'm trying to do is query the size of all mailboxes and e-mail that information to myself once a week. Currently I log into our exchange server and run a shell command to output this information to a text file. That command is:

```
Get-MailboxStatistics |where {$_.TotalItemSize -gt 1MB} | sort $_.TotalItemSize |FT DisplayName,ItemCount,TotalItemSize >c:\size.txt
```

I would really like to have this automated and e-mailed to myself once a week. How would I go about setting this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the following in a script file and schedule it to run once a week:

```
Get-MailboxStatistics | `
   Where-Object {$_.TotalItemSize -gt 1MB} | `
   Sort-Object TotalItemSize | `
   Format-Table DisplayName,ItemCount,TotalItemSize |`
   Out-File c:\size.txt

Send-MailMessage -From you@domain.com -To you@domain.com -SmtpServer smtp1 -Subject 'Weekly Mailbox Statistics Report' -Attachments c:\size.txt
```

Comment: Three years later and I'm still using this script. It's been very stable and helpful.